# Issue with return types in NgRx Effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

Using NgRX effects version 8.5.1 - with the new create functions I am having an issue with my observable stream from the effect.

With this code, I get an error in the console: `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

```
loadAllSeasons$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SeasonActions.loadSeasons),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectIfAllSeasonsLoaded))),
  filter(([action, allSeasonsLoaded]) => !allSeasonsLoaded),
  mergeMap(() => this.seasonService.getSeasons()),
  map(seasons => SeasonActions.loadSeasonsSuccess({seasons}))
));
```

I figured the issue could be to do with the dispatching of the `loadSeasonsSuccess` action not returning the correct type, so I modified that line to this:

```
map(seasons => this.store.dispatch(loadSeasonsSuccess({seasons})))
```

However I now get a compile error `Type 'Observable<Void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>...'` and the same console error.

If I switch the filter to `allSeasonsLoaded` rather than `!allSeasonsLoaded`, the code runs fine, but obviously no seasons are fetched.

Comment: What about using tap instead of map?

Comment: It seems correct to me. You must not change to `this.store.dispatch`. This is a runtime error, you should use debugger to find out which one is undefined. What is the implementation of `seasonService.getSeasons`?

Comment: Can you show us how you define `loadSeasonsSuccess` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `map` operator on the inner observable:

```
loadAllSeasons$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SeasonActions.loadSeasons),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectIfAllSeasonsLoaded))),
  filter(([action, allSeasonsLoaded]) => !allSeasonsLoaded),
  mergeMap(() => 
    this.seasonService.getSeasons().pipe(
      map(seasons => SeasonActions.loadSeasonsSuccess({seasons}))
    )
  )),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  map(seasons => of(new SeasonActions.loadSeasonsSuccess({seasons})))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.